# Cross site lookup columns

Tags: lookup-column

If I have site structure as per the below:

Site Collection

**-Main Site**

**-Site 1**

-SS 1.1

-SS 1.2

**-Site 2**

-SS 2.1

-SS 2.2

If I have a list in SS 1.1 is there any way in which I can create a column lookup to that list from SS 2.1?

Using SP2013.

Comment: that's not possible out of the box, you need to write a field type yourself and deploy it as solution. Are you able to do that?

Comment: I have done a quick search and found some code I can edit for linking across sites. However I don't know how to specifically create a new field type for me to actually place this code.

Comment: have you experience with visual studio?

Comment: I've got some experience of visual studio express but never in the context of SharePoint

Comment: you could try this: https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/Create-a-SharePoint-Lookup-Column-to-Another-Site.aspx

Comment: I can only really do that if I have all the lists sitting at a higher level in the site structure. I'll have a look at the visual studio method and see where I get with that. Thanks